Plaid Adding Institute To Existing User
I am trying to allow my application to link to multiple institutes for a user using Plaid. I am not sure if this would require a user to have multiple access tokens, each associated with a different institute or if there is a way to initialize link with my existing access token and allow the user to select another institute to associate with that token.
I have not found a direct answer to this anywhere and I just want to make sure I am not using more access tokens than is completely necessary. I am thinking something like Rocket Money's ability to add institute in settings when you have existing accounts from another institute.

Per the Plaid docs:
https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/glossary/#item
"An Item represents a login at a financial institution. A single end-user of your application might have accounts at different financial institutions, which means they would have multiple different Items...Each Item linked within your application will have a corresponding access_token."
Or in other words: you cannot have a single access_token associated with multiple Items.
